# Can I make a getter recomputed when another getter changed in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, getter

I am using this getter in vuex:

```js
authority_count (state, getters) {
      return getters.dataView?.getUint16(4, true) || state.pack.authority_count;
}
```

I am expecting authority_count to be state.pack.authority_count when dataView is null, and after I loaded a file in the page, I wish authority_count to be recomputed when the loading is finish, after dataView is filled with data loaded from file. How can I make this work?

The problem is when I make getters.dataView return an DataView, authority_count still returns state.pack.authority_count.

---

Using file input to get binary data from file, and fill in to arrayBuffer, which access by dataView getter.

[Loading arrayBuffer](https://github.com/xiongmao86/dns-playground/blob/c75692804740f3eeb1d824c5092cd40e559e26a8/src/App.vue#L3-L4)

[Loading dataView](https://github.com/xiongmao86/dns-playground/blob/c75692804740f3eeb1d824c5092cd40e559e26a8/src/store/index.js#L148-L151)

Logs in authority_count

```sh
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
getters.dataView:  null
state.pack.authority_count:  5
```

Comment: What problem did you encounter with your code?

Comment: The problem is after dataView is not null, getter  authority_count is still state.pack.authority_count.

Comment: It sounds like the getter is not running again after `dataView` is set.  Can you show the code that sets `dataView`?  And test that by logging both `getters.dataView` and `state.pack.authority_count` inside of this getter

Comment: I am loading from binary file and then pass to arrayBuffer then to dataView, I have provided the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in the linked project:

1. Changes to Vuex state (e.g. `arrayBuffer`) must be made only in a Vuex mutation:

```js
mutations: {
  setArrayBuffer(state, payload) {
    state.arrayBuffer = payload;
  }
},
```

and call it like this:

```js
reader.onload = (event) => {
  this.$store.commit('setArrayBuffer', event.target.result);
}
```

2. The component's `arrayBuffer` must be a computed to stay synced with Vuex:

```js
data () {
  return {
    pack: this.$store.state.pack
  }
},
computed: {
  arrayBuffer() { // You could use `mapState` instead, same thing
    return this.$store.state.arrayBuffer
  },
  buffer () {
    return [...new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer)]
      .map (b => b.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, '0'));
  }
},
```

You will need to do the same thing with `pack` if you want it to be synced with Vuex.

Comment: I have changed like you suggest, but console.log are just the same.  [diff](https://github.com/xiongmao86/dns-playground/commit/fd4c292ab11f8df3fd80dc3e6bf6879f7f0acb70)

Comment: Use the console to test:  Is there data in `onload` callback?  Is it passed to `setArrayBuffer`?

Comment: The `DNSBuffer` is working, so I think `onload` has data and is passed to `setArrayBuffer `, I can use separate getters to give small piece of data, and another getter to collect all the data into an object, and pass.it into the DNSPacket component, that is another way to change data source gradually, I didn't realize that.

Comment: Nice.  Once you confirm that `state.arrayBuffer` is being changed in the mutation, it's a given that `getter.dataView` must change as well.  Keep testing all the connections with console.

Comment: I found out a way to avoid testing on dataView and just put showing logic into an `<div v-if="this.arrayBuffer">`. But I can not make the decision that whether I should push on to learn the stuff which would be helping future development or just settle to the solution that is workable, and doesn't bother what's going on and why it would work that way. What would you do if you were me?

Comment: Sometimes one, sometimes the other.  You do you :)  Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/4vrd5huw/) for you to study

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your time and effort. Have a nice day.